# Is there a c# calendar control that can show free / busy information by default?

Tags: c#, calendar

I am writing a c# web app which has a booking system incorporated. I have a requirement for a calendar control so that people can make a booking on a particular date.

What I need to be able to do is only allow "available" dates to be selectable. Is there a calendar control you can somehow bind to a datasource so you can return whether that date is currently available?

I can probably write something myself to do this, but don't want to waste time if there are tools / controls already out there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you just wanna mark the dates or disable them, but WPF DatePicker has DisplayDateStart, DisplayDateEnd and BlackoutDates property. It is just a question of styles how do you show / display them. Ofcourse in case of BlackoutDates, they are not selectable.

More info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker_properties.aspx